# Limit the number of elements in each row of matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, element

I have a matrix like:

```
A
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    5    7
[2,]    2    4    6    8
```

And a vector of number of element to be limited in each row (other elements will be transform to 0).

```
 c
[1] 2 3
```

I want to obtain (with at least loop as possible):

```
B
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    0    0
[2,]    2    4    6    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m <- matrix(1:8, nrow = 2)
sel <- 2:3

#create a integer matrix of col numbers
#use this to create a logical matrix indicating 
#if the col numbers are greater than the threshold
#this relies on vector recycling
subs <- col(m) > sel

#assign to subset
m[subs] <- 0
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    0    0
#[2,]    2    4    6    0
```